# Quiero abrir un Teams desde un link en una app que muestra un listado de Teams en Microsoft Teams

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2017, vscode

Muy buenas,
Estoy creando una aplicación en Microsoft Teams en la que saca un listado de Teams que tienen un link a estos.
El problema es que cuando pincho en el link me sale una ventana intermedia que me pide con que aplicación quiere abrirla.
¿Cómo puedo deshacerme de esto y abrir la URL directamente en la pestaña?, o que me lleve al Teams directamente.

Quiero conseguir el efecto a si buscas un Teams en el buscador de Microsoft Teams, pinchas en el Team encontrado y accede directamente a él.

He probado a hacerlo con DeepLinks de la forma:
`https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/{TeamsAppId}/{TeamsTabId}?webUrl={myURL}` pero no me funciona, me sale esa ventana intermedia pidiendo la aplicación en la que quiero abrirla.

Comment: Buenas Marcelo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] y [ask] para aprender como funciona el sitio y como hacer mejores preguntas. Quizá tu pregunta sea muy amplia, has mirado la documentacion?  Un saludo! (y gran foto de perfil. este es un sitio libre de la nación del fuego )